# With horizontal transformations, does k(-x + c) cause a translation to the right?

Tags: functions, transformation

I was going over homework problems and had a question where the transformations 2f(3(-x+2))-4 were applied to f(x) = √x

For the √x point (0,0), that answer I got after the transformations was (-2, -4), as I thought I needed a horizontal translation 2 left. However, the answer sheet says it should be (2, -4)

Does this mean that the -x causes the translation to be reversed, or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not simply a matter of the translation being rightward instead of leftward.
The fact that it is $-x$ instead of $x$ causes the entire graph to be mirror-imaged.

There are various ways to get the end result. One is to mirror-image the graph around the $y$ axis and then translate $2$ units to the right.
Another is to translate left and then mirror-image the graph.
If you allow reflections around other lines you have even more ways to get the result.

For the particular case of the image of $(0,0),$ 
consider when it will be true that $3(-x+2) = 0$.